# Confusion about how to properly filter 2D numpy array representing a scalar field using its meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to understand why the code block under the "naive filtering" comment line doesn't produce the expected result of extracting the corner of but code block under the "correct result" comment line does:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# creating the underlying x and y axes
nx, ny = 101, 111
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, nx)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, ny)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='xy')

# computing the scalar 2D field
f = np.exp(-1.1*X*X - 0.9*Y*Y + 0.7*X*Y)

# saving figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(f)
plt.savefig('field_full.png')

# data filters
mx = x > 0
my = y < 0
MX, MY = np.meshgrid(mx, my, indexing='xy')

# naive filtering
mf = (MX & MY)
lf = f[mf].reshape(len(x[mx]), len(y[my]))

# saving figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(lf)
plt.savefig('field_filtered_naive.png')

# correct result
mf = (MX & MY).T
lf = f.T[mf].reshape(len(x[mx]), len(y[my]))

# saving figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(lf)
plt.savefig('field_filtered_correct.png')
```

I'm honestly totally stumped about this and I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

**EDIT:** I realized after reading @Mercury's answer that I wasn't exactly clear about what kind of answer I was looking for.

I know how to get the result I'm expecting just fine. What's got me baffled is the WHY aspect of it. It makes absolutely no sense to me WHY the "naive filtering" code bloc doesn't produce the correct result right away.

@Mercury also pointed out that the following would work:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# creating the underlying x and y axes
nx, ny = 101, 111
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, nx)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, ny)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='xy')

# computing the scalar 2D field
f = np.exp(-1.1*X*X - 0.9*Y*Y + 0.7*X*Y)

# saving figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(f)
plt.savefig('field_full.png')

# data filters
mx = x > 0
my = y < 0
MX, MY = np.meshgrid(mx, my, indexing='xy')

# filtered field data
mf = (MX & MY)
reduced_nx = len(x[mx])
reduced_ny = len(y[my])
lf = f[mf].reshape(reduced_ny, reduced_nx)

# saving figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(lf)
plt.savefig('field_filtered.png')
```

In a way, this code disturbs me even more and I've explicitly defined `reduced_nx` and `reduced_ny` to emphasize WHY. The original field `f` has dimensions `nx` by `ny`, but its filtered version `lf` has dimensions `reduced_ny` by `reduced_nx` instead of the other way around.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong or maybe I'm just an idiot, but the above "shadow transpose" shall we say looks like a huge design flaw to me and can lead people to make mistakes that are very hard to notice when you don't know what kind of result you are expecting in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `np.meshgrid()`, the function needs to know how to "order" the points in the newly created 2D grid. It is decided by providing the "indexing" argument with either "xy" (the default and what you do in your script) or "ij".

Numpy documentation for meshgrid explains it in the "Notes" section:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html

Consider the following example.

We want a grid like this:

[image]

Let's see the code:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,2)
y = np.arange(100,104)

print("\nindexing xy:")
X1, Y1 = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing = "xy")
print(X1)
print(Y1)
print(X1.shape, Y1.shape)

print("\nindexing ij:")
X2, Y2 = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing = "ij")
print(X2)
print(Y2)
print(X2.shape, Y2.shape)

print("\nreshape:")
Xr = X1.reshape(x.shape[0], y.shape[0])
Yr = Y1.reshape(x.shape[0], y.shape[0])
print(Xr)
print(Yr)
print(Xr.shape, Yr.shape)
```

The first two parts produce the following output:

```
indexing xy:
[[0 1]
 [0 1]
 [0 1]
 [0 1]]
[[100 100]
 [101 101]
 [102 102]
 [103 103]]
(4, 2) (4, 2)

indexing ij:
[[0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1]]
[[100 101 102 103]
 [100 101 102 103]]
(2, 4) (2, 4)
```

Notice how the points of the 2D grid are the same, but they are ordered differently (with the arrows indicating axis in our xy-plot):

[image]

In the third part of the code, we reshape the result from the xy indexing (somehow what you do in your naive filtering), and this is what happens:

```
reshape:
[[0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1]]
[[100 100 101 101]
 [102 102 103 103]]
(2, 4) (2, 4)
```

Still the same points, still the same "(2, 4)" shape as in the "ij" indexing, but the actual order of the data is different. In fact, we can no longer create those x and y arrows, as in the previous image. This is way your naive filtering gives "unexpected" results.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation makes it very clear what is happening in the background. Though it does make it obvious that there is, in my opinion, a design flaw in that filtering my 2D array (which flattens it) forces me to reshape it into its intended shape manually which requires to know, in advance, which indexing method is going to be used, with no easy way to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

In your correct result code, you've transposed `mf` and `f`, but you are still reshaping to `(len(x[mx]), len(y[my]))`, same as what you are doing in the naive filtering. This implies that the reshaping in the naive filtering may be wrong. So try reshaping to `(len(y[my]), len(x[mx]))` in the naive one.

```
# naive filtering
mf = (MX & MY)
lf = f[mf].reshape(len(y[my]), len(x[mx]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you haven't exactly answered my question (or maybe I'm the one who didn't make it clear enough). My question was really about WHY it works the way it does.

True, your code gives the same result as the "correct result" bloc, but it also displays a fundamental design flaw in that `f` was designed to have dimensions `nx` by `ny`, not the other way around. So it's, in my opinion, an absurdity for `lf` to have its axes inverted. Do you get what I mean ?